# Kafka: what's the best way to dynamically determine the number of partitions in a topic from the consumer side?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, partition

We have Java code that manages a thread pool of Kafka stream consumers reading a four partitions topic (therefore we have four consumer threads).

*What's the recommended way to retrieve the number of partitions dynamically, so that the initialization code in the thread pool cat set up the right number of threads?*

Being able dynamically adjust to an increasing number of partitions is not a requirement.

Looking at the Java API (v.0.8.1) I couldn't find a straightforward way to do it. Currently I'm browsing the Scala source code and I see promising classes (Scala solutions to this problem are welcome as well), however I also wanted to ask the community about this in case somebody already found a nice way to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to have the consumer thread count match the partition count. Just make a number of consumer threads that maximizes your ability to consume (e.g. ~2x cores if you're doing a lot of CPU, more or fewer if you're doing a lot of I/O, depending on its nature).

Comment: Re: "You shouldn't need to have the consumer thread count match the partition count" is trying to do this a bad thing?. Regardless of the scenario, I'm curious about how this would be done with the current API.

Comment: It's not bad, but it's not necessarily good either; partitioning is mostly about the _ability_ to distribute consumption (and probably a bit about server throughput), whereas consumer threads are mostly about parallelizing the work your consumers do.

Comment: To answer your specific question, no, there is not (to my knowledge) a way to ask Kafka how many partitions there are. Your best bet is to inspect the information in zookeeper directly.

Comment: My understanding is that if you attach more consumers than partitions, you'll have idle consumers. Which raises the question if you experience a load spike on a topic, and you've already got the same number of consumers as partitions...how are you supposed to add additional consumers to handle more of the load?

Answer (score 4):

More threads than partitions will end up with idle threads, because each partition can only be consumed by only one consumer thread. On the other hand, more partitions than threads will end up with threads consuming more than one partition each and then affect the performance.

So to make it easy, just use exactly the same number of threads as partitions. If you ever find performance becomes a problem, maybe you should have more partitions and then more threads.